# Add Complex Logic To A Twilio Whatsapp Bot

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, survey

I am developing a Whatsapp Bot in Twilio to collect survey data Covid-19 related. However, i want to add complex logic in my program task. For example, i only want to display a question asking if the user is pregnant or not if the user has selected female as her gender. Plus i want to add a range of the questions asking weight and height.

Below is the sample code for my task

````
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": "Thank you for making the time for this survey. Your answers help us improve the service!"
        },
        {
            "collect": {
                "name": "csat_answers",
                "questions": [

                    {
                        "question": "Have you completed this survey before??",
                        "name": "first_time",
                        "type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Please enter your username",
                        "name": "usernmae"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "How old are you?",
                        "name": "age",
                        "type": "Twilio.NUMBER"
                    },
                        {
                        "question": "What Gender are you",
                        "name": "Gender"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "Are you pregnant?",
                        "name": "pregnant",
                        "type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "What is your height (cm)?",
                        "name": "height",
                        "type": "Twilio.NUMBER"
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "What is your weight (kg)?",
                        "name": "weight",
                        "type": "Twilio.NUMBER"
                    }
                ],
                "on_complete": {
                    "redirect": {
                        "method": "POST",
                        "uri": "task://complete_survey"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You will need to introduce logic in your Autopilot assistant, static JSON will not provide this capability.

[How to Use Twilio Functions with Twilio Autopilot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jOwcruws5U)

If you are not a developer but a builder, you will want to look at Twilio Studio, to graphically draw out your survey flow and handle survey state.

[Conduct a Survey with Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-conduct-a-survey)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no way to do conditional Collect flows in Autopilot so that logic would need to be a part of your app code. You can implement that conditional logic with Autopilot using [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions), our serverless environment tool for Node.js applications.

This [Node.js quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/quickstart/node) has some of what you're looking for.

You could have one Autopilot task which redirects to the Function which would check what the user said. That [Redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/redirect) task could include this JSON:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
                "collect": {
                    "name": "pregnant_collect",
                    "questions": [
                        {
                            "question": "Are you pregnant?",
                            "name": "pregnant",
                            "type": "Twilio.YES_NO"
                        }
                    ],
                    "on_complete": {
                        "redirect": {
                            "method": "POST",
                            "uri": "https://YOUR-TWILIO-FUNCTION.twil.io/Function_Name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    ]
}
```

and then use a conditional in the Twilio Function that above Task redirects to (above, it's *https://YOUR-TWILIO-FUNCTION.twil.io/Function_Name*) to check what the user said. The Twilio Autopilot task could include this JSON:

```
 exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
        //Memory from the answered question
        let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);
        //array of "actions" objects 
        let actions = [];
        //response item to return/add to responseObject in Actions
        let responseItem;

        //get answer from Memory
        let pregnant_answer = Memory.twilio.collected_data.pregnant_collect.answers.pregnant.answer; 
        //Yes or No
        if (pregnant_answer === "Yes") {
            responseItem = {
                "say": "WHATEVER YOU WANT TO SAY FOR YES"
            };
            actions.push(responseItem);
        } 
        else {
            responseItem = {
                "say": "WHATEVER YOU WANT TO SAY FOR NO"
            };
            actions.push(responseItem);
        }
        responseItem = {
            "redirect": {
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "task://next_task"
            }
        };

        actions.push(responseItem);

        let responseObject = {
            "actions": actions
        };
        callback(null, responseObject);
    };
```

Let me know if this helps at all! <3